# Unable to render posted date in node--article.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I'm attempting to render the posted date of an article in a specific way. I understand that there is a

```
Display author and date information.
```

Checkbox in the content type editor. However I don't believe that would resolve my issue. I'm using the domain access module and the articles on the domains using a different theme cannot be altered. Certainly not how they're displayed anyway.

Is there a way to programmatically grab the posted date from within the template? Is there something similar to

```
print render($content['body']);
```

That I can use to render that information? Or is there a function I can call that contains that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to render the date by performing

```
print format_date($node->created, 'article');
```